# Russian equivalents of "À peine le temps de dire ouf" in French

Tags: выражения, французский

> **À peine le temps de dire ouf** qu’il est tombé comme une brique sur le lit...

- Literally: *(He must have been dead tired.) **No sooner / Hardly had he said phew** than he fell onto the bed like a bag of bricks...*
- Or, more naturally: *He fell onto the bed like a bag of bricks **in the twinkling of an eye*** -- {Implicit: *almost as soon as X*}

In practice, this hyperbolic expression is used to refer to the extraordinary swiftness of some action. As indicated by the exaggerated "*dire ouf* *{say phew}*", the construction "*À peine X que Y {Hardly X than Y}*" is used purely for hyperbole here (as opposed to its usual usage where you compare two actions having actually taken place, almost one after another).

---

As another example, to express the idea of "how time flies by", you can say:

> Les semaines filent à toute allure.  **À peine le temps de dire ouf** qu'on se retrouve à la fin de la semaine !

- *A whole week flies by in no time. You find yourself at the end of the week **before you know it**.*

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in Russian? (Not a literal translation of the phrase)

Comment: I think, “не успев” could do it. “Не успев сказать ‘Уф!’ он повалился на кровать как мешок кирпичей.”

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest will be:

> Не успеешь глазом моргнуть

or (in the past tense)

> Не успел глазом моргнуть

**UPD**

If you demand someone to do something fast you can say "одна нога здесь, другая там", but this expression means to go somewhere. For example:

> Срочно сходи в магазин за колбасой. Быстро, одна нога здесь, другая там.

Answer (score 2):

Consider also a literal equivalent `он и охнуть не успел`. However, it is usually applied for events which you have not caused (week passing - yes, falling asleep - no).

For falling asleep, there is a special form `заснул раньше, чем голова коснулась подушки`.

Comment: Maybe not [охнуть], but [ахнуть]? I personally never heard [и охнуть не успел], always [и ахнуть не успел]. But it is possible that in some regions of Russia they say [и охнуть не успел].

Comment: @Tchibi-kun Google shows comparable number of hits on both, of course you can always check ruscorpora.

Comment: [охнуть] means to say [Ох!] [ахнуть] means to say [Ах!] [эхнуть] means to say [Эх!] [ойкнуть] means to say [Ой!] If  in your [он и охнуть не успел] you've ment [он не успел даже «Ой!» сказать] then you are correct on using [охнуть].

Comment: `ох` is as close to `ouf` from question as possible, hence the choice. You can basically use either one.

Answer (score 1):

Russian has two similar analogs for "in the twinkling of an eye".

> В мгновение ока он, как подкошенный, повалился на кровать.

works better for the former, while the one proposed by @Dmitriy:

> Неделя пролетает быстро. Глазом моргнуть не успеешь, как уже выходные.

works better for the latter.